# Same folder history for "save folder" as "change folder"?

Tags: mutt

I use mutt as my e-mail client and have only one major annoyance. If I want to save an e-mail to a folder that I've used before as a "save folder", then I can use the up-arrow to navigate to the folder name.

Now if I want to *change into* that folder, the up-arrow only gives me names of folders I've *changed into* before. It appears that mutt has two different folder histories for these two purposes.

How can I configure mutt so that only one history is used for both purposes? (By the way, I'm pretty sure that older versions of mutt behaved exactly as I wanted, but unfortunately I can't tell the version number.)